# pgr_dijkstra return values in lat/long

Tags: postgis, pgrouting

I'm new to PostGIS and pgRouting and I'm using the `pgr_dijkstra` functionality and I need to convert the values it returns in the format lat/long, is that possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you done the [pgRouting workshop](http://workshop.pgrouting.org/)?
You best start with it, if you're new to the topic.

In [chapter 8.1](http://workshop.pgrouting.org/chapters/wrapper.html#return-route-with-network-geometry) you will then see how to return a route with geometry. With a little modification you can adapt it to your needs:

```
SELECT seq, id1 AS node, id2 AS edge, cost, 
       ST_X(b.the_geom), ST_Y(b.the_geom), b.the_geom FROM pgr_dijkstra('
                SELECT gid AS id,
                         source::integer,
                         target::integer,
                         length::double precision AS cost
                        FROM ways',
                30, 60, false, false) a LEFT JOIN ways b ON (a.id2 = b.gid);
```

Comment: then is it easy to convert from geometry to lat/lang?

The query I'm doing as it is, is already returning the geometry. Thanks

Comment: Your coordinate reference system needs to be lat/lon. This is the case if you have WGS84 for example.